# When/how does @NgModule get evaluated?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, node-modules

I've 3 applications which share a common framework so there's currently a bunch of duplicated code (basic ui layout, common code such as loggers etc, security/keycloak auth wrapper).  I've extracted all the duplicate module code but also want to simplify the app module declaration itself.  I've created an "Application" class containing a static method which takes a couple of params and builds an NgModule definition based on common modules, concatenating the passed in ones...

```
public static Define({modules, states, defaultState}) {
    return {
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule,
            TreeModule,
            NgbModule.forRoot(),
            ToastModule.forRoot(<ToastOptions>{animate: 'flyRight', positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'}),
            UIRouterModule.forRoot(<RootModule>{ states: states.concat({name: 'app', url: '/app', component: ShellComponent}), useHash: true, otherwise: defaultState }),

            CommonModule,
            DialogsModule,

            LayoutModule,
        ].concat(modules),
        providers: [
            {
                provide: Http,
                useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new AuthHttpService(backend, defaultOptions),
                deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
            }
        ],
        bootstrap: [ UIView ]
    };
}
```

Each application can then simply call this and just list its specific modules, states and an initial/default state like this...

```
@NgModule(
    Application.Define({
        modules: [
            PatientIdentityModule,
            RecordViewerModule,
            ResourcesModule,
        ],
        states: [
            {name: 'app.resourceList', url: '/resourceList', component: ResourcesComponent },
            {name: 'app.resourceEdit', url: '/resourceEdit/:itemAction/:itemUuid', component: ResourcesComponent },
            {name: 'app.patientIdentity', url: '/patientIdentity', component : PatientIdentityComponent},
            {name : 'app.recordViewer', url: '/recordViewer', component : RecordViewerComponent }
        ],
        defaultState : { state: 'app.recordViewer', params: {} }
    })
)
export class AppModule {}
```

This works great when all the code is together but when I try extracting the Application class and building a node module library, I then get

`Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'`

Any ideas or am I going about this completely the wrong way!?

`Angular 2.1.0, typescript 2.0.6, webpack 1.13.2`

Comment: `but when I try extracting the Application class` What do you mean?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/oAFTojPQQIAtkxPqs42E?p=preview

Comment: Have you tried it with systemjs?

Comment: I mean taking that class out of my project, putting it into a seperate project building that project as a node module library, then re importing into the original (npm link). As for systemjs, no I haven't all the projects are currently webpack.

Comment: Yes, my code pretty much boils down to your plunker. And it works perfectly like that. But what I'm now trying to do is take the application.ts file out and make it into a node module so it can be used by other applications.